# Como usar o Sum com subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como posso usar o *sum* com uma *subquery* dentro?
Tentei de várias maneiras, mas não consegui.

Quando tento colocar o *sum* logo após o *select* principal, aparece a mensagem de que não posso usar função de agregação com agregado ou consulta.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), (
        SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), COUNT(*))
        FROM (
            SELECT PG_DATA
            FROM SPG010
            WHERE YEAR(PG_DATA) = '2017'
                AND MONTH(PG_DATA) = '01'
                AND PG_MAT = RA_MAT
            GROUP BY PG_DATA
        ) AS dias_trab
    ) / 26)) AS presenca
FROM SRA010 AS sra
WHERE 
    (
        RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR 
        RA_DEMISSA > CAST(YEAR('20170116') AS VARCHAR) + CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH('20170116'))) + RTrim(MONTH('20170116')) AS VARCHAR) + '31'
    ) AND 
    SUBSTRING(RA_CC, 1, 5) = '13604'
```

Comment: O que retorna quando você faz apenas o subselect?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em utilizar a `subquery` dentro de um `SUM`. Você pode contornar esse problema mudando a sua `subquery` para um `JOIN`:

```
select sum(convert(decimal(5, 2), x.quantidade)) as presenca
  from sra010 as sra
       left join (select convert(decimal(5, 2), count(*)) / 26 as quantidade,
                         pg_mat
                    from (select pg_data,
                                 pg_mat
                            from spg010
                           where year(pg_data) = '2017'
                             and month(pg_data) = '01'
                           group by pg_data, pg_mat) as dias_trab) x on x.pg_mat = ra_mat
 where (ra_sitfolh not in ('D', 'A')
         or ra_demissa > cast(year('20170116') as varchar)
                         + cast(replicate('0', 2 - len(month('20170116'))) + rtrim(month('20170116')) as varchar)
                         + '31')
   and substring(ra_cc, 1, 5) = '13604'
```

**Observação:** Sem a estrutura das tabelas e o que é esperado do resultado a única resposta possível é genérica. Sua `query` pode ser melhorada, porém pra isso precisamos de uma visão mais específica.

Answer (score 1):

> *Como posso usar o sum com uma subquery dentro?*

A documentação da função [Sum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187810.aspx) informa que o parâmetro deve ser uma expressão. E, em outra parte, cita que "*(...) Funções de agregação e **subconsultas não são permitidas***". Ou seja, seu código deve ser reescrito.

---

Sum() é uma das várias [funções de agregação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173454.aspx) disponíveis em T-SQL. Geralmente as funções de agregação são utilizadas em conjunto com a cláusula [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673.aspx), mas podendo ser utilizadas de forma isolada em alguns casos específicos.

Por exemplo, para somar os salários pagos em 2016 para cada funcionário da empresa, uma forma seria:

```
-- código #1
SELECT P.idFunc, Sum(P.Salário_Mensal) as Salário_Anual
  from Pagamento as P
  where P.AnoPagamento = 2016
  group by P.idFunc;
```

Observe que a lista de colunas somente pode conter expressões da cláusula GROUP BY e funções de agregação, além de constantes.

Mas, se for para somar todos os salários pagos em 2016, podemos ter:

```
-- código #2
SELECT Sum(P.Salário_Mensal) as Total_salários
  from Pagamento as P
  where P.AnoPagamento = 2016;
```

Neste caso não há a cláusula GROUP BY, pois todas as linhas foram consideradas como um único grupo.

Dito isto, você deve considerar cada subconsulta como uma consulta individual para aplicar as regras de utilização de função de agregação.

Somente como exemplo, para calcular o total de salários pagos em 2016 podemos ter

```
-- código #3
SELECT Sum(Salário_Anual) as Total_salários
  from (SELECT P.idFunc, Sum(P.Salário_Mensal) as Salário_Anual
          from Pagamento as P
          where P.AnoPagamento = 2016
        group by P.idFunc
       ) as T;
```

Observe que ambas consultas, a interna e a externa, utilizam a função Sum(), mas, no caso da subconsulta há a cláusula GROUP BY, pois a soma é realizada para cada agrupamento.

Complementando, para boa legibilidade do código, bem como facilitar a manutenção, sugiro que quebre o código em partes, utilizando [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972.aspx). Isto é possível quando não há correlação entre as consultas. Por exemplo:

```
-- código #4
with Salários_Func as (
SELECT P.idFunc, Sum(P.Salário_Mensal) as Salário_Anual
  from Pagamento as P
  where P.AnoPagamento = 2016
  group by P.idFunc
)
SELECT Sum(Salário_Anual) as Total_salários
  from Salários_Func;
```